# How many ways to do dependency injection?

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, object-manager

How many ways to do dependency injection?

Object Manager,Constructor injection and Method injection
Is that it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe so. As per the official blog of Magento 2 - If you find more please let me know

Link: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html

Comment: yes, I have read the same. That's all think so.